# How to compiling PJProject for iphone error

Tags: xcode, ios5, pjsip

I am trying to compile PJSip for iPhoneSDK 5.1. I am running Lion 1.7.3 and Xcode 4.3.3. I did not find any helpful information about compiling it. I am not even sure it's got support for the iphonesdk 5.1. I didn't get any information about it on the project's website. I am not sure if something changed in the compiler from the last iPhoneSDK release but these are the errors i'm getting 
I followed the steps on the project's website I change the config_site.h added the lines

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

Then moved the header to the location pjlib/include/pj/

I the configure-iphone file i've change the line

```
./aconfigure --host=arm-apple-darwin9 --disable-floating-point --disable-sdl $*
```

to

```
./aconfigure --host=arm-apple-darwin10 --disable-floating-point --disable-sdl $*
```

sow it would compile for iPhoneSDK 5.1

when i rune the configure-iphone everything i get no errors but when i run make sep i get this errors at samples.mak

> make -f Samples.mak depend 
>   make[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.

and while running make

> "_pjsua_aud_subsys_start", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  _pjsua_media_subsys_start in libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin10.a(pjsua_media.o)
> ```
>
> "_pjsua_vid_subsys_start", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  _pjsua_media_subsys_start in libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin10.a(pjsua_media.o)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: *** [../bin/pjsua-arm-apple-darwin10] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [pjsua] Error 2
>
> make: *** [all] Error 1

Did anybody solve this problem , or can provide a solution to compile Pjsip for iphonesdk5.1 whit Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: You can refer to [this link][1], i tried before. thanks.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/just-info-how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-t

Answer (score 0):

type `./configure-iphone` in terminal at your pjsip directory

remember to install command-line tool via Xcode

when configure is done

try to `make dep` && `make clean` && `make`