# Set up PJSIP on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, asterisk, pjsip

I followed the steps at this link:
[How To Build and Compile PJSIP for Xcode, Using sample code IPJSUA to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-to-test)

There were a few steps I wasn't super sure about, and I am fairly certain that is why I am getting so many errors

I didn't know where to type these lines in the configure_site.h file:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

So I put them at the top above everything.

I also didn't really know where to type these lines in the configure-iphone file:

```
          DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer

IPHONESDK=iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
```

So I put them at the top underneath and outside the if statement.

When I try to build the ipjsua xcode project I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_app_config", referenced from:
      _keepAliveFunction in pjsua_app.o
      _on_playfile_done in pjsua_app.o
      _app_init in pjsua_app.o
      _default_config in pjsua_app.o
      _parse_args in pjsua_app.o
      _on_call_state in pjsua_app.o
      _on_incoming_call in pjsua_app.o
      ...

    "_app_config_init_video", referenced from:
      _app_init in pjsua_app.o
  "_arrange_window", referenced from:
      _on_call_video_state in pjsua_app.o
  "_cli_console_app_main", referenced from:
     _app_main in pjsua_app.o
  "_console_app_main", referenced from:
      _app_main in pjsua_app.o
  "_current_call", referenced from:
     _on_call_state in pjsua_app.o
      _on_incoming_call in pjsua_app.o
  "_destroy_cli", referenced from:
     _app_destroy in pjsua_app.o
   "_find_next_call", referenced from:
      _on_call_state in pjsua_app.o
  "_log_call_dump", referenced from:
      _on_call_state in pjsua_app.o
  "_my_atoi", referenced from:
      _parse_args in pjsua_app.o
  "_setup_cli", referenced from:
      _app_init in pjsua_app.o
  "_stdout_refresh", referenced from:
      _parse_args in pjsua_app.o
      _app_main in pjsua_app.o
       _stdout_refresh_proc in pjsua_app.o
   "_stdout_refresh_quit", referenced from:
       _app_main in pjsua_app.o
       _stdout_refresh_proc in pjsua_app.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And when I try to build it to my device I get over 129 errors.

I've been struggling with installing this library now for the past 3 days. I would really like to just build my own SIP stack, but I hear that is an insanely difficult task.

Any help on how to rectify this problem I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Indeed it seems that this has started happening in the most recent GIT sources. Try downloading the sources from the [tar.gz source link](http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.1/pjproject-2.1.tar.bz2) for the released version. The correct filename is config_site.h and not configure_site.h, but the contents are correct. Also, you don't need anything in the configure-iphone script.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: @NolanAnderson have you fixed that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not
I'm trying exosip and having a little bit more success; I can build the files and create the .a file, however, when I go to link the libraries in my project I get a TON of errors. 
I'm running out of time/options :/

Comment: Just an FYI, for the PjSip files I tried to build I got all the same errors as above. 
Since I am getting a ton of errors related to  *Undefined symbols for architecture i386* I am guessing my architecture doesn't support however PJsip was built... But I am not sure. I am really unfamiliar with computer architecture. But if I were to wager a guess, that would be it.

Comment: @NolanAnderson You can "lipo -info your-library.a" to see if it is built for i386 or not

Comment: @entropy, thanks for the advice. 
I actually have everything built and the application runs both on the simulator and on my device (not my iPhone 5, however, but that's because, *I think*, of the iPhone 5's ARMv7's architecture, which I am still trying to figure out how to configure to get it to work).
The problem I am having now is actually getting the software to connect to my Asterisk server... I am not sure what the problem is, but the software is not connecting to the IP address I give it. 
I'll post about it when I get a bit more time

Comment: is it running @NolanAnderson ???