# PJSIP build issue

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compilation, pjsip

Environment: OS X 10.9.3, Xcode 5.1, PJSIP-2.2.1
I want to build simple PJSIP, the shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="pjproject-2.2.1"
CONFIG="pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h"

if [ ! -r $SOURCE ]; then
    echo 'PJSIP source not found. Trying to untar...'
    tar -xjf $SOURCE.tar.bz2
fi

cd $SOURCE

touch $CONFIG
echo > $CONFIG
echo "#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1" >> $CONFIG
echo "#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>" >> $CONFIG

./configure-iphone
#make dep && make clean && make

echo Done.
```

It runs OK and .a files are created, for example `pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9`. But when I use them to my iOS project, it failed with `Endianness must be declared for this processor`, `PJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN is not defined!`, `PJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN is not defined!` and so on. I think PJSIP is not built correctly. Anyone who knows?
I have checked [Compile PJSIP for iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369062/compile-pjsip-for-ios7)

Answer (score 5):

I add this to project's Preprocessor Macros then it runs OK: `PJ_AUTOCONF=1`

Comment: how did you add this ?? please tell me

Comment: Well it's been a while @Eesha but you can add it on the Build Settings of your target, then go to the Preprocessing section, select the Preprocessor Macros setting and add PJ_AUTOCONF=1 :-)

Comment: @MiguelRojasCortés This issue has been solved. Please take a look at my recent questions.