# PJSIP compile error - library not found on Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pjsip

I want to create sample App using `PJSIP` on `iPhone`.

I have followed steps in the Link 
[How To Build and Compile PJSIP for Xcode, Using sample code IPJSUA to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-to-test)

firstofall, if i tried running configure-iphone file with changing `devpath` - i get some kind of warning error.
and without changing it goes fine.

and when i build project finally, i gets error that `-libavfilter` library not found.
and i also see that in `xcode->Libraries` 7 libraries shows Red(`libavcodec.a` ,`libavutil.a`,`libswscale.a`,`libavformat.a`,`libavresample.a`,`libavfilter.a`,`libavdevice.a`)

Please Tell what should i do.
I am using Xcode-5.1.1 having latest SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an auto-build script. Place it anywhere and execute, it will automatically download pjsip-2.2.1 and build it with OpenSSL and multi-architecture supported. Then you can open the sample project, it may still have some red libraries, but you can safely delete them and continue to build.

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE_URL="http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.2.1/pjproject-2.2.1.tar.bz2"
PROJECT_DIR="pjproject-2.2.1"
ARCHIVE="${PROJECT_DIR}.tar.bz2"

copy_libs () {
    DST=${1}

    if [ -d pjlib/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf pjlib/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d pjlib/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir pjlib/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjlib/lib-${DST}/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a

    if [ -d pjlib-util/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf pjlib-util/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d pjlib-util/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir pjlib-util/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjlib-util/lib-${DST}/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a

    if [ -d pjmedia/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf pjmedia/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d pjmedia/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir pjmedia/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjmedia/lib-${DST}/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a 
    cp pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjmedia/lib-${DST}/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjmedia/lib-${DST}/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjmedia/lib-${DST}/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjmedia/lib-${DST}/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a

    if [ -d pjnath/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf pjnath/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d pjnath/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir pjnath/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp pjnath/lib/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjnath/lib-${DST}/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a

    if [ -d pjsip/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf pjsip/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d pjsip/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir pjsip/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp pjsip/lib/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjsip/lib-${DST}/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjsip/lib-${DST}/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjsip/lib-${DST}/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp pjsip/lib/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a pjsip/lib-${DST}/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a 

    if [ -d third_party/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        rm -rf third_party/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    if [ ! -d third_party/lib-${DST}/ ]; then
        mkdir third_party/lib-${DST}/
    fi
    cp third_party/lib/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp third_party/lib/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp third_party/lib/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp third_party/lib/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a
    cp third_party/lib/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a third_party/lib-${DST}/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a
}

lipo_libs () {
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjlib/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjlib/lib-armv7/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjlib/lib-armv7s/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch arm64  pjlib/lib-arm64/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjlib-util/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjlib-util/lib-armv7/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjlib-util/lib-armv7s/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch arm64  pjlib-util/lib-arm64/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjmedia/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjmedia/lib-armv7/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjmedia/lib-armv7s/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjmedia/lib-arm64/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjmedia/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjmedia/lib-armv7/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjmedia/lib-armv7s/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjmedia/lib-arm64/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjmedia/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjmedia/lib-armv7/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjmedia/lib-armv7s/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjmedia/lib-arm64/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjmedia/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjmedia/lib-armv7/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjmedia/lib-armv7s/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64 pjmedia/lib-arm64/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjmedia/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjmedia/lib-armv7/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjmedia/lib-armv7s/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjmedia/lib-arm64/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjnath/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjnath/lib-armv7/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjnath/lib-armv7s/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjnath/lib-arm64/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjnath/lib/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjsip/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjsip/lib-armv7/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjsip/lib-armv7s/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64 pjsip/lib-arm64/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjsip/lib/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjsip/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjsip/lib-armv7/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjsip/lib-armv7s/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjsip/lib-arm64/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjsip/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjsip/lib-armv7/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjsip/lib-armv7s/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjsip/lib-arm64/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   pjsip/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  pjsip/lib-armv7/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s pjsip/lib-armv7s/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  pjsip/lib-arm64/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output pjsip/lib/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  third_party/lib-arm64/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  third_party/lib-arm64/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  third_party/lib-arm64/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64  third_party/lib-arm64/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64 third_party/lib-arm64/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -arch i386   third_party/lib-iPhoneSimulator/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7  third_party/lib-armv7/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                         -arch armv7s third_party/lib-armv7s/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                            -arch arm64 third_party/lib-arm64/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a \
                      -create -output third_party/lib/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a
}

if [ -d ${PROJECT_DIR} ]; then
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm -rf ${PROJECT_DIR}
fi
if [ ! -f ${ARCHIVE} ]; then
    echo "Downloading source code..."
    curl -o ${ARCHIVE} ${SOURCE_URL}
fi
tar xvjf ${ARCHIVE}

echo "Creating config.h..."
echo "#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1 
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>" > ${PROJECT_DIR}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h

cd ${PROJECT_DIR}

CFLAGS="-I${PWD}/../OpenSSL/ios/include"
configure="./configure-iphone --with-ssl=${PWD}/../OpenSSL/ios"

echo "Building for armv7..."
make distclean > /dev/null 2>&1
ARCH="-arch armv7" \
$configure
make -j dep
make clean
make -j
copy_libs armv7

echo "Building for armv7s..."
make distclean > /dev/null
ARCH='-arch armv7s' \
$configure > /dev/null
make -j dep > /dev/null 
make clean > /dev/null
make -j > /dev/null 2>&1
copy_libs armv7s

echo "Building for arm64..."
make distclean > /dev/null
ARCH='-arch arm64' \
$configure > /dev/null
make -j dep > /dev/null
make clean > /dev/null
make -j > /dev/null 2>&1
copy_libs arm64

echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator..."
make distclean > /dev/null
DEVPATH=/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/ \
ARCH="-arch i386" \
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0" \
$configure > /dev/null
make -j dep > /dev/null 
make clean > /dev/null
make -j > /dev/null 2>&1
copy_libs iPhoneSimulator

echo "Making universal lib..."
make distclean > /dev/null
lipo_libs
```

If you use cocoapods, I recommend this:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'pjsip'
```

cocoapods really makes things much easier.

Comment: This made pjsip sample project run like a charm. Only problem is that custom shell script executes every time (both on build and run) and takes too long to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I anyways was able to install PJSIP on Device.

and one Black screen writ tens PJSUA , with IP Address and port at the bottom was shown at device.

I want to know what should i done after that..
Can you please explain from where this ip address coming ?
Actually we have some server configuration done ,i hav to create app to make calls and all.
please tell me where in my code i can make all these things.
if possible explain from Basic.
Thanks

Comment: The best way to learn PJSIP is to read through the sample code. :D     The code is a little long. The first time I used PJSIP, I also didn't know where to start. FINALLY I chose to read through the code...     The sample application is a telnet server, you can telnet to the IP address shown on the UI, type `help` to get a commend list.

Comment: Thanks Saiqi , just one more lil help if you can..
now i am running PJUSA app through Xcode in my Device.
and i am using terminal to send commands,i am able to connect to Simulator,but i am not able to connect to my device. Is there any other configuration need to be done?

Comment: @Stackia I am getting error of file not found on PJSIP... please help me