# Implement PJSIP for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I want to implement audio and video call using pjsip but unable to integrate the same. Could you please guide me how to implement audio and video call in iOS version? Any clue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is to broad. Please, provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: @fewlinesofcode, Thanks for your response. I did not get proper documentation how I can implement PJSIP in IOS project. Can you help me.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-to-test

Comment: Follow this PJSIP developer build guide to build basic iOS with [PJSIP](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone)